# Why Azure AppService instances showing different % of CPU and Memory utilization in Pay-As-You-Go -S3 Plan?

Tags: azure-web-app-service

**I Pay-As-You-Go subscription with S3 plan**

[image]

**Having scale out settings like Min 2 instance Max 4. Based on CPU and Memory consumption it will add 1 more instance**

[image]

[image]

**Why first instance showing 82% CPU utilization while other is <40% CPU utilization ?** **I would expecting equal utilization.**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

based on R&D i come to know because application sticky session instance does not sharing equal utilization.

Comment: I believe that you are correct, and that ARR affinity should be checked. If a session is started on instance 1 with ARR affinity enabled, it will not be load balanced to a new server when a scale out rule is triggered.